# High Risk Of Death When Contracting Hepatitis A After Contracting Hepatitis C

Tags: hepatitis, health-education

Is it true that there is a high risk of death if one contracts Hepatitis A after they contract Hepatitis C?  If so, you'd think there ought to be more noise about this in health publications and also in the media.

Comment: Are you sure you mean hepatitis **A** and C? All I can find is on **B** and C (or C and HIV)

Comment: Hepatitis A clearly exists and shows up in Google searches, so I'm guessing you're talking about Google hits with respect to searches involving complications of two diseases.  And I agree - there seems to be nothing online about it!

The original source and basis for my question is House M.D., season 6 or 7.  The entire cast agrees that, given a patient who has Hepatitis C, if they infect him with Hepatitis A, there is a 15% it will cure him outright, but an 85% chance it will kill him.  The entire cast went along with this plot point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Fulminant Hepatitis Associated with Hepatitis A Virus Superinfection in Patients with Chronic Hepatitis C](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199801293380503), out of 17 patients with chronic hepatitis C infection who also got infected with hepatitis A, 6 died, so about one third.

In an [Italian population based study](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199806113382413), 77 patients with chronic hepatitis C (52 with hepatitis C, 25 with hepatitis C and hepatitis B) also got infected with hepatitis A. None died from the hepatitis A infection. This is a published letter to the journal the first study appeared in - the researchers from Italy wrote in because they were surprised by the high mortality rate in the US study, as they had seen no such correlation.

[Hepatitis A virus vaccination in persons with hepatitis C virus infection: consequences of quality measure implementation](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22371026) pooled data from 10 studies and puts the mortality rate for hepatitis C patients with a hepatitis A superinfection at around 7 percent (95 percent confidence interval: 1.24-42.12)

That figure of 85 percent dying that the TV show *House MD* mentioned is made up.

Vaccination against hepatitis A is recommended for chronic hepatitis C patients by

- the [World Health Organization](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs164/en/)
- [the CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/vpd-vac/hepa/in-short-adult.htm#who)
- and [the NHS](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Hepatitis-A/Pages/Vaccination.aspx)

Comment: I am willing to believe the statistics were made up on House M.D.  My question, though, was whether there is a high risk of death when one contracts HepA after they contracted HepC.  You first study has a mortality rate of 35%!  The third has it as 7%.  So perhaps it's not high", but instead _startling_.  So I'd say, whatever it is, it sounds like it's more than enough to start publicizing this more!

And I also think there's no question - you have provided very good source material!